# Translation of BelongsTo in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I use for translations fields in Nova

```
Text::make(__('Name User'), 'name')
```

But I don't understand the manual to make the title of the BelongsTo fields translatable

> Title Attributes
>   When a BelongsTo field is shown on a resource creation / update screen, a drop-down selection menu or search menu will display the "title" of the resource. For example, a User resource may use the name attribute as its title. Then, when the resource is shown in a BelongsTo selection menu, that attribute will be displayed:

Well... On my code, this fails because translations produces in name of model, not in Label of relation Ship.

```
BelongsTo::make(__('User'), 'users')->withMeta([
  'belongsToId' =>  $this->user_id ?? auth()->user()->id
])->hideFromDetail()
```

```
local.ERROR: Class 'App\Nova\Usuario' not found {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Nova\\Usuario' not found at /home/abkrim/Sites/albaridnova/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Fields/BelongsTo.php:118)
```

#### Code on Nova\User

```
public static $model = 'App\\User';

public static $title = 'email';

public static $search = ['id', 'name', 'email'];

public static function availableForNavigation(Request $request)
{
    return $request->user()->isAdmin();
}

public static function label()
{
    return __('Users');
}

public static function singularLabel()
{
    return __('User');
}
```

When show User resource not problem. Labels translations are done.

But if go to resource Mailbox, field BelongsTo not show translations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because if you don't specify the third argument (resource) on the `make` method, Nova will think that your resource is called in the same way as the Label (eg: label: `User` then resourceName: `User`) and will try to search for that resource class.

Obviously you can override that by passing the resource class as third argument:

```php
// Add the import of your resource if its class
// is not in the same directory as this file
BelongsTo::make(__('User'), 'users', User::class)->withMeta([
  'belongsToId' =>  $this->user_id ?? auth()->user()->id
])->hideFromDetail(),
```

Comment: A lot of thanks. I had already corrected my problems after reviewing the doc. I saw that it was necessary to pass three parameters, Label, table and model. Thank you @mdexp

Comment: No problems, in future you can also inspect the source code that is really well documented and "eloquent". Sometimes peeking at the source is quicker than looking up in the docs. Anyways, if you feel so mark my answer as correct, or post one yourself to mark as correct as this may help other people with the same issue in the future